# Partial Least Squares regression - coefficients vs loadings

Tags: partial-least-squares

In partial least squares regression, what is the difference between the regression coefficients and the loadings for each independent variable in each component? Specifically, I understand in evety component, each of the independent variables has a coresponding loading. Does each variable also have a regression coefficient? What is the relationship between the loading vector and the coefficients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your independent variable matrix is $m\times n$, that you have $m$ observations and $n$ variables.

For each PLS component (AKA latent variable), you get a loading vector ($n \times 1$), so for $h$ components the size of loading matrix ($P$) is $n \times h$. These loadings are calculated for both interpretation and algorithmic purposes but **they have no use for prediction**.

On the other hand, SIMPLS algorithm (I believe the most popular PLS flavor) also involves calculation of weight matrix ($W$), which has the same size as loading matrix. This orthogonal matrix $W$ is used to calculate $X$ scores ($T$):

$T = X\cdot W$

which is then multiplied by $Y$ loadings ($Q$) for prediction:

$\hat{Y} = T \cdot Q'$

Therefore, the regression coefficients ($\hat{B}$ that is $n\times1$ for a single dependent variable) that can be used to predict $Y$ directly from $X$ can be calculated:

$\hat{B} = W \cdot Q'$

All in all, one obtains a loading vector for each component whereas for different number components a same sized yet different regression coefficients are produced.

As far as I know, a similar logic applies to other PLS algorithms too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm still not clear if a regression coefficient is generated for every independent variable - i.e, all $m$ of them, or only a subset.

Comment: Yes, a coefficient for each variable is obtained. But not m but n of them since n is the number of variables.

Comment: I suggest re-reading the answer with looking at the matrix/vector sizes carefully, it should help clear things up.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Just one more detail: in your example, what is the dimension of the matrix Q? And Y-hat? I'm asking because I have output from a PLS regression and I have a set of regression coefficients as well as loadings. I get that the coefficients is B-hat and the loading P is n x h.

Comment: I guess Q should be $h$ x 1. Also what is the difference between Q and Q'?

Comment: Q is 1 x h. Q' ıs Q transposed. So, Q' is h x 1

Comment: Thanks again very much. Intuitively, what information is expressed by the loadings versus the regression coefficients? Can the regression coefficients be taken as a measure of the variable's relative importance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93350/discussion-between-user2450223-and-thegd).